# error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName ""

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I am start etcd(3.3.13) member using this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name infra2 \
  --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes.pem \
  --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes.pem \
  --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem \
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://172.19.104.230:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls https://172.19.104.230:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls https://172.19.104.230:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster \
  --initial-cluster infra1=https://172.19.104.231:2380,infra2=https://172.19.104.230:2380,infra3=https://172.19.150.82:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
```

but the log shows this error:

```
2019-08-24 13:12:07.981345 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60474" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.003918 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60478" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.004242 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60480" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.045940 E | rafthttp: request cluster ID mismatch (got 52162d7b86a0617a want b125c249de626e35)
2019-08-24 13:12:08.046455 E | rafthttp: request cluster ID mismatch (got 52162d7b86a0617a want b125c249de626e35)
2019-08-24 13:12:08.081290 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60484" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.101692 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60489" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.102002 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60488" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.144928 E | rafthttp: request cluster ID mismatch (got 52162d7b86a0617a want b125c249de626e35)
2019-08-24 13:12:08.145151 E | rafthttp: request cluster ID mismatch (got 52162d7b86a0617a want b125c249de626e35)
2019-08-24 13:12:08.181299 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60494" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.201722 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60500" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
2019-08-24 13:12:08.202096 I | embed: rejected connection from "172.19.104.231:60498" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")
```

I search from internet and find the reason is: should give all etcd node ip in hosts config when generate CA cert,but I config all my etcd node ip in csr.json,this is my csr.json config:

```
{
    "CN": "kubernetes",
    "hosts": [
      "127.0.0.1",
      "172.19.104.230",
      "172.19.150.82",
      "172.19.104.231"
    ],
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 2048
    },
    "names": [
        {
            "C": "CN",
            "ST": "BeiJing",
            "L": "BeiJing",
            "O": "k8s",
            "OU": "System"
        }
    ]
}
```

what should I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the cfssl generate command, you should provide the IPs of the hosts running etcd.:

```
cfssl gencert \
  -ca=ca.pem \
  -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
  -config=ca-config.json \
  -hostname=IP1, IP..,IPN \
  -profile=kubernetes \
  kubernetes-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kubernetes
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone suffers the same problem as me, please try to correct your ntp configuration and time setting, refer: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/8603#issuecomment-1151800718